# Best way to insert video (vimeo and youtube) into content

Tags: wysiwyg, files

What is the best way to embed videos into content? Often it's not ideal just to have video content at the beginning or end end of page content. More often then not it something like 
[text]
[video]
[text]

I'm looking at the best way to insert video content into a page while keeping a video content type field. I also want to avoid just adding video embed code into the full html body editor as then it's impossible to use the video in other places.

How do I go about adding a view field and then have a 'placeholder' for which to render the video in the middle of the text content?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way by far, is to use [video embed field](https://www.drupal.org/project/video_embed_field). I have built a video sharing site with a co-worker that generates very high rates of traffic. He built the site mostly by himself 80% in a couple of days, and the video embed module was used heavily for the management of video content types.

Comment: Do you know if this is the best option for Drupal 8?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer - I would most probably try to use the same approach, seeing this was so easy to implement in D7 but have not tried on D8 - your mileage may vary.  Good day to you amigo!

Answer (score 3):

I am using [Video Embed Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/video_embed_field) which is specifically made for this purpose. I've used it to embed Youtube videos so far, but I'm sure it works for Vimeo as well.

Answer (score 2):

Media and its associated modules (Media Wysiwyg etc) is supposed to do that, but it still has issues.

Your best bet is [Scald](https://www.drupal.org/project/scald), as it allows for a library that you keep and you can drag and drop from that library into text fields that you predesignate to accept media atoms. You can do that with all media. It also has an Atom reference field allowing you to reference Media from any drupal entity the way nodereference or entityreference do. And there is a series of tutorials by the developers on Youtube.

Comment: thanks but it's kinda not what I was after because I wan to capture the video content associated with each node.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 8.6+ now has integrated Media Library with Images and Video support.

Video Embed Field plugs into the video type as well if you wish to still use it.

Use the core Media library with Entity Browser, it works great once the setup is complete!